# How to generate table from entities

Tags: java, seam

I am currently working on a seam project using eclipse jpa tools; is it possible to automatically generate sql tables from my entity definitions? If so, how do I achieve this?

Comment: [This documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/tasks020.htm) might help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the JPA implementation you are using.
With Hibernate you can specify '`create`' or '`update`' in the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` properties in `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="yourPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <description>Your Persistence Unit</description>
    <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Possible values for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property are:

- `create`: create database tables and indexes at startup
- `create-drop`: create database tables and indexes at startup and drop at shutdown
- `update`: when the application starts, check the database schema and update as needed adding missing tables and columns
- `validate`: when the application starts, check the database schema and fails if there is some missing table or column.